# The test loss changes strangely with learning rate 0?

Tags: tensorflow, yolo

I'm trying to study the performace of YOLOv2. I have implemented the YOLOv2 in tensorflow with the backbone of mobilenet.

After setting the learning rate=0, weight decay=0, BN's is_training=False, the loss of test dataset is still changing unexpectedly.

I just want to know if there is any other possible parameter may influence the test loss.

Comment: learning rate of zero sounds strange. try some small numbers like .0001

Comment: With the above setting, the whole network should be fixed and the loss should also be fixed. But results are not the way we expected. I'm trying to figure out what else influence the final loss.